# How to interpolate only less than 3 consecutive Nan values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, nan

I have a 500x600 matrix containing some NaN values. I want to interpolate places where there are less than three NaNs (possibly an average of the preceding, following values) and for all the other places where there are more than 3 consecutive NaN values I want to leave them as Nan values. I have already looked at http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/34481-interpolate-nans-only-if-less-than-4-consecutive-nans but even the accepted answer doesn't work. (I realise this one is for 4 consecutive values but it doesn't work either way).

Comment: do you mean 3 consecutive nans in a row? in col? both? Diagonal also counts?

Comment: @Ibezito I'm really sorry I wasn't clear with the question. I've tried this and it works great. I've tried it on my matrix and looks like this code does both rows and columns? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by writing 3 consecutive nans you mean 3 consecutive nans in a row or column, you can use the following approach:

1. For each row, use convolution to determine for each sequence of nans if its shorter than 3.
2. use the [following approach](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/34481-interpolate-nans-only-if-less-than-4-consecutive-nans) to fill each line in the matrix.
3. fill the columns by transposing the result and executing the function again.

Code:

```
%generates example array
data = rand(5,5); 
data (1,2:4) = nan;
data (2:5,2) = nan;
data (:,4) = nan;

%fills all relevan nans in a row
data2 = interpolateNanRows(data );
%fills all relevant nans in a column
out= interpolateNanRows(data2')';
```

Auxiliary functions:

```
function res = interpolateNanRows(data)
%zero padding
dataPad = zeros(size(data,1)+2,size(data,2)+2);
dataPad(2:end-1,2:end-1)=data;

%generates relevant nan maps
nansMap = isnan(dataPad);
irrelevantNans = conv2(double(nansMap),[1,0,0,0,1],'same')>0 & nansMap;

%fills each row
for ii=1:size(dataPad,1)
    filledRow = interpolateRow(dataPad(ii,:));
    %ignores irrelevant values (more than 3 consecutive nans)
    filledRow(irrelevantNans(ii,:)) = nan;
    dataPad(ii,:) = filledRow;
end
%generates output
res  = dataPad(2:end-1,2:end-1);
end


function filledRow = interpolateRow(row)
%receives a vector of values, and perform interpolation in regions of nans
if sum(isnan(row))==0 || sum(isnan(row))==length(row)
    filledRow = row;
    return;
end
nanData = isnan(row);
index   = 1:numel(row);
filledRow   = row;
filledRow(nanData) = interp1(index(~nanData), row(~nanData), index(nanData));

end
```

results:

```
data2=
0.6386       NaN       NaN       NaN    0.6671
0.4805       NaN    0.3171       NaN    0.7771
0.1184       NaN    0.0124       NaN    0.6860
0.2455       NaN    0.3011       NaN    0.8014
0.7761       NaN    0.7239       NaN    0.2833


out =

0.6386    0.6457    0.6528    0.6599    0.6671
0.4805    0.3988    0.3171    0.5471    0.7771
0.1184    0.0654    0.0124    0.3492    0.6860
0.2455    0.2733    0.3011    0.5512    0.8014
0.7761    0.7500    0.7239    0.5036    0.2833
```